# if statement between values of two pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I want to make an if statement with the values of two pandas data frames (the values I want to compare are in column 0):

EDIT:

First of all I wanted to check the number of times at which the value of df1 is greater than the value of df2.

```
for row in df1:
    if df1[0] > df2[0]:
       Print('Ok')
    else:
       Print('not OK')
```

and what I get is:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
>   a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

EDIT No. 2:

Since I hadn't time to try all your proposals and due to the fact that I needed a quick solution, here is what I got along with:

```
excessLoadB1l=[]

indexYB1=loadC1C2B1.index.tolist()

tempLB1=energyBalanceB1['sumSupply_B1'].tolist()

for item in tempLB1:

    if item < 0:

        item=item

    else:

        item=0

    excessLoadB1l.append(item)

excessLoadB1=pd.DataFrame({'excessLoadB1':excessLoadB1l}).set_index([indexYB1])
```

I created a list out of the positive and negative values

> tempLB1=energyBalanceB1['sumSupply_B1'].tolist()

which I wanted to separate in two different DataFrames. I borrowed the index from

> indexYB1=loadC1C2B1.index.tolist()

and for the positive values:

```
excessSupplyB1l=[]

indexZB1=loadC1C2B1.index.tolist()

tempSB1=energyBalanceB1['sumSupply_B1'].tolist()

for item in tempSB1:

    if item > 0:

        item=item

    else:

        item=0

    excessSupplyB1l.append(item)


excessSupplyB1=pd.DataFrame({'excessSupplyB1':excessSupplyB1l}).set_index([indexZB1])
```

Comment: Please indicate what `do something` and `do something else` represent, e.g. are you creating a new column based on your condition?

Comment: On basis of the if statement I want to merge two other data frames, e. g. if value of df1[0] > df2[0] merge df3 and df4 ...

Comment: This is non-trivial. I suggest you put together a complete [mcve] with small example dataframes.

Comment: Relevant note: DataFrames are dict-like, and their keys are column labels. So if you run, e.g., `for x in df: print(x)`, all you see are the column names of `df`, with no data. The solution is to loop with `for i, row in df.iterrows()`

Comment: would be nice accepting an answer or even reacting to the reactions given. people  have put in effort to help you.

Comment: @Zanshin you're right. But the truth is that I hadn't time to try one of your proposals yet. I got along with a different solution using lists to DataFrame with pandas. See the edit.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly faster

```
for i, j in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    if j[0] > df1[0].iloc[i]:
        print("OK")
    else:
        print("Not OK")
```

Comment: wouldn't you want `j[1]` in this case to check the values?

    `...`
       `if j[1] > df1[0].iloc[i]:`
           `...`

Answer (score 1):

```
count = 0    

for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row[0] > df2.loc[i,0]:
        print('Ok')
        count += 1

    else:
        print('not OK')

print ('%d times item in df1 was greater than df2' %count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are looking for.

If you are comparing single columns from different dataframes:

```
df1[0].gt(df2[0])
```

If you are comparing all columns of one dataframe with a single column from another dataframe:

```
df1.gt(df2[0], axis=0)
```

If you are comparing all columns in two dataframes:

```
df1.gt(df2)
```

Add this to any of the above to get "Ok" and "not OK" instead of True, False:

```
.replace([1, 0], ['Ok', 'not OK'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you might combine the two dataframes and then add a column with np.where:

```
df['result'] = np.where(df1['column1'] > df2['column2'], 'ok', 'not ok')
```

+

```
df[df.result == 'ok'].count()
```

in addition, borrowing from b2002;

```
df_ = df1[0].gt(df2[0])
(df_ == 1).sum()
```